# Using a key word to mark the beginning of reading a csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a csv with lots of information and then the actual data within the words $$SOE and $$EOE. It looks like this:

```
************************************************
 (many lines of info)
************************************************
$$SOE
 1978-Jan-01 00:00, , ,    52.06147,   20.73814,
 1978-Jul-01 00:00, , ,   109.59527,   22.86676,
 1979-Jan-01 00:00, , ,   132.73982,   18.48124,
...
$$EOE
************************************************
(More info)
************************************************
```

How can I use pandas (or another library if needed) to ignore all of the info and start reading the data after $$SEO and before $$EOE?

Thank you so much!

Comment: you can combine `open("file",'r').readlines()` with `itertools.dropwhile` and `itertools.takewhile`

Answer (score 0):

Pandas.read_csv has 'skiprows' and 'skipfooter' options, so if you know how many rows that stuff takes up at the top and bottom of your file you can pass the number of rows in to those options when reading the file.